# freezing header in a table in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, freeze

Here, I have one table, i want to fix that header while scrolling

**JS**

```
<script>
$('#scroll').scroll(function(){
if ($('#scroll').scrollTop() > 10){
    $("thead").css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '68px'
        });
}else{
    $('thead').css({
        position: 'static'
    });
}
});
</script>
```

This is working Perfectly, but design is changing.

[LIVE DEMO](http://testing.twomini.com/)

could anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqDC5/)

Comment: I believe it is happening because of `position: 'fixed'` try changing it to static and it might wok.

Comment: Why you wont try to use http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/ or  http://www.tablefixedheader.com/ or http://fixedheadertable.com/

Comment: can anyone make example

Comment: @NareshKamireddy check out my answer bub, try using my piece of code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datatables plugin](http://datatables.net/) with different table types([fixed header table, example](http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/))

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for fixed header, i used http://fixedheadertable.com/.

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
$('#scroll').scroll(function(){
if ($('#scroll').scrollTop() > 10){
    $("thead").css({
            position: 'static',
            top: '68px'
        });
}else{
    $('thead').css({
        position: 'static'
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Use this, you are changing position of header to fixed while scrolling, which is causing the issue

Comment: @NareshKamireddy your heading is having fixed position while being scrolled, in my opinion that is causing the issue. it should be either static or relative.

Comment: Here i want to fix the header and design also, both i need

Comment: by fix do u mean fixed position or do u want it to stay where it is while scrolling?

Comment: header is not freezing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42554/discussion-between-aditya-ponkshe-and-naresh-kamireddy)

Answer (score 0):

`Position: fixed` will ignore all other markup on the page and position your element relative to the browser window. Regardless of the markup I think you'll want to use `position: absolute` and apply `position: relative` to the table's containing element.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/QxW6v/1/

Comment: can you give some example

Comment: Set `#scroll` to `position: relative` and have your jQuery set `<thead>` to `position: absolute` instead of fixed on scroll. You'll need to add `left: 0; right: 0;` to the thead element as well.

Comment: in that case header is not freezing

Comment: and you left <thead> as `top: 68px`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cqDC5/2/ this is as close as I'm going to get, you've added pixel dimensions to all your th and tds which forces the header to be wider than its container. Get rid of those and you should be ok.